# xCode 6.3.2 Crash [UIViewController .cxx_destruct]

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, memory-management

I have converted an application written in Objective-C, previously using SQL, now changed to CoreData.

Issue I identify so far is when I changed `NSObject` to `NSManagedObject` in only one of class I am getting this stupid crash in `ViewController` after `View` is completely dismissed:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Control stopped at `@implementation Viewcontroller`, if I changed model being used in this class back to `NSObject` there is no crash, the view is dismissed properly.

I have found nothing so far about this crash what does this crash even means?

Is there any way to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code which caused `[UIViewController .cxx_destruct]`

```
Article *article = [Article new];
```

Fixed with this

```
NSManagedObject *article = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Article"
                                                         inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Answer (score 1):

I also have faced similar issue, Added below code to dealloc solved my issue.

```
-(void) dealloc {
   [_managedObjectContext reset];
}
```

OR

```
-(void) dealloc {
   _objectFromContext = nil;
   _managedObjectContext = nil;
}
```

For more details refer this [link](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2012/Apr/msg00071.html)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Indeed this is correct what you are saying but this does not solved my problem. I was doing something wrong which i found now, I am adding it in answer.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Cool, Looking forward to your answer. Accept the answer so it became helpful to others as well.. OR Upvote it.. If you think so then  only.